# ActionForm class in struts

Tags: java, struts2

I am developing struts paging using display tag lib and I am using struts struts-2.3.4.1. But when I am importing `ActionForm` class its giving error. My question is that is `ActionForm` class is deprecated if yes so what is alternate of this.

Comment: It's not just deprecated, it doesn't exist: S2 is nothing like S1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well i am not sure what exactly you are doing so its hard to say anything.first concept which i want to clarify here is *Struts2 is not Struts1* and they are entirely different in terms of architecture and implementations.

Struts2 do not have any such requirement and its action class work as a data model also so there is no concept of Action forms, though while creating your action class you can extends ActionSupport which is a convenient class being there and provides a lot of functionality out of the box for you.

```
public class MyAction extends ActionSupport{

  public String execute() throws Exception{

  }
}
```

this is all you need to do and you are ready to write your first action, though its not necessary to name method as execute and you are free to use any name as per your needs and use case.

Answer (score 2):

In Struts 1 you had to extend the ActionForm class in any class you wanted to use as a form bean. This requirement was removed in Struts 2 allowing you to use a POJO (plain old Java object) - including the action class itself, if you wish - as the form bean.

If you're working with Struts 2 then the alternative is to use any class you like because you don't need to extend the ActionForm class at all.